R: avoid as.Date remove leading zero
in R, when I run: as.Date("0945-10-06 10:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d") the output is "945-10-06".
However, I want to preserve that leading zero of the year, so the output should be "0945-10-06".
Any ideas how to achieve that?
Thanks!

afaik that only works with a string

You are confusing an object’s value with its representation. Dates are dates (not strings! the “output” you are showing is merely its string representation), and years are numbers. They inherently don’t have “leading zeros” — a leading zero is part of the representation, not of the value of a number. Furthermore, dates in R by default are printed/formatted using one of a number of common conventions, and I am not aware of any convention that represents years with a leading zero. If you want to achieve this you’ll have to implement your own function that formats date objects to strings.

As already said, representation is a string, so just add 0 character to your string, like paste0("0", as.Date("0945-10-06 10:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d")).
